# How to switch account with ibmcloud CLI

Tags: ibm-cloud-tools

After logging in IBMCloud with account(say account-1) by using CLI, how to switch to another account(say account-2) without logging out?

commands:
`ibmcloud login --sso`, then select account-1.

Does IBMCloud CLI have a command for account switching?

Answer (score 9):

This is how we switch an account via CLI at IBM cloud

login to account

```
$ ibmcloud login -a cloud.ibm.com --sso
$ ibmcloud account list
$ ibmcloud target -c <<accpunt_id>>

example:
$ ibmcloud target -c 0XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Targeted account IPOPS Test - PROD (0XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX) <-> 20XXXX2



API endpoint:      https://cloud.ibm.com

Region:            us-south

User:              g***l@xxx.com

Account:           g account - (XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX) <-> 2041792

Resource group:    No resource group targeted, use 'ibmcloud target -g RESOURCE_GROUP'

CF API endpoint:
Org:
Space:
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following command to switch accounts, assuming you know the Account ID/GUID of the account where you'd like to switch:

```
ibmcloud target -c ACCOUNT_ID
```